# base_pose_ground_truth does not correspond with .world from Stage

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I have created simple world with some obstacles and added a robot at a given (x1,y1) position. Now when I run stageros I can see the robot at the correct position (according the scale plotted on the Stage GUI). However when I publish the topic /base_pose_ground_truth/pose/pose/position I get the position as x = y1 and y = -x1. Which essentially means the frame if rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. I am confused on why that is happening since both the .world and the topic are part of stage?

Appreciate the help.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48117/base_pose_ground_truth-does-not-correspond-with-.world-from-stage/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question is a replicate of [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/28561/why-base_pose_ground_truth-isnt-publishing-the-real-position-in-stageros/). Unfortunately I think it is still an open issue.
cheers

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0